# select record where condition 1 followed condition 2

Tags: mysql

In my project I have query like.

```
$mainquery="SELECT * 
            FROM project 
            WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and Status='In Progress' 
            order by projectid";
```

and

```
$mainquery="SELECT * 
            FROM project 
            WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and Status='Not Started' 
            order by projectid";
```

now I want combine both and want all record where Status='In Progress' and then Status='Not Started'. I tried this.

```
$mainquery="SELECT * 
            FROM project 
            WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and (Status='In Progress' or Status='Not Started') 
            order by projectid";
```

but it gives combine result with Status='In Progress' and Status='Not Started'. I want first all record of Status='In Progress' and then all record of Status='Not Started'.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort the results? If so, try this `ORDER BY Status='In Progress' DESC, projectid`

Comment: change order by to `... ORDER BY status, projectid;`  gives 'In Progress'  in ASC order of projectid then 'Not Started' in ASC order of projectid

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might be useful

```
SELECT * 
      FROM project 
      WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and (Status='In Progress' or  
      Status='Not Started') 
      order by case when Status like 'In Progress' then 0 else 1 end, Status
```

REF:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96446/mysql-order-by-first-condition-in-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

```
$mainquery="SELECT * FROM project WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and 
           (Status='In Progress' or Status='Not Started') 
           order by  Status <> 'Not Started',projectid";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mainquery="SELECT * 
        FROM project 
        WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and (Status='In Progress' or Status='Not Started') 
        order by Status, projectid";
```

Comment: `...ORDER BY status, projectid;`  not projectid, status

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean to say is that you're getting **all the results** with status = "In Progress" and those with status = "Not started", **interleaved**, sorted solely by the "projectid". 

Rather you want to see the results for "In Progress" first and then "Not Started" (both sorted on the basis of projectid), then you must do one of the following things :

$mainquery = 
"SELECT * 
            FROM project 
            WHERE ProjectType = 'Current Projects' and 
(Status = 'In Progress' or Status = 'Not Started') 
            
order by Status, projectid ";

This will first sort your results on the basis of **status(alphabetically** **ascending** , ie,  "In Progress" before "Not started") and then within the results having same status, it will sort on the basis of their "projectid" **numerically(ascending).**

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and Status='In Progress' order by projectid
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM project WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and Status='Not Started' order by projectid
```

Above will give you records with first condition and then 
records with second condition provided number of columns for both query remain same.

```
 SELECT * FROM project WHERE ProjectType='Current Projects' and (Status='In Progress' OR Status='Not Started') order by projectid
```

Above query should also work in your case.